# Is it possible to offer clipboard content as autosuggestion in React-native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm building an QR code authentication for a mobile app (in React-native). This QR code is sent by mail to the users. The problem is that some users want to acces this QR code on their phone, so I want to make it possible to copy the code from their inbox and offer this code as an autosuggestion on their phone. I've seen it before on multiple mobile apps, but I can't find any documentation on the web. Anyone here who can help me out?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Clipboard } from 'react-native';

getContentFromClipboard = async () => {
    const content = await Clipboard.getString();
    return content;
 };
```

Comment: @Reza thank you! I've already read the current documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/clipboard), but the problem I struggle with is how to suggest Clipboard content in the autosuggestion field above a mobile keyboard.

Comment: You are already using the clipboard. What is the problem?

Comment: @hongdevelop Offering the clipboard as an suggestion (like autocomplete) when focussing on a input field.

Comment: Use the OnFocus function .